# how to export socket.io function

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

guys i have a basic socket connection and i want to send a message to clients after test request.
I tried normal exports and eventemitter but couldn't manage it

```
//this is server.js file
const express = require("express");
const testRoutes = require("./routes/testRoutes");

const app = express();
  
//Socket.io connection
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

//Socket.io communication
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("socket on");
  socket.on("newMessageToServer", ({ message, username }) => {
    console.log("messagefromclient", message, username);
    io.emit("newMessageToClient", { message, username }); //<-- i want to reach this line from another file
  });
});

//Routes
app.use("/test", testRoutes);

//Server
const port = process.env.port || 5000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening " + port);
});
```

so i want to send to clients a message aftere hitting /test/test endpoint downbelow

```
//this is testRoutes.js file
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("testsocket");
  // -- I want to use socket here like this
  //io.emit("newMessageToClient", { message, username });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `testRoutes` export a function that accepts the `io` interface and returns the router. Eg

```js
// testRoutes.js

module.exports = (io) => {
  const router = express.Router();

  router.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("testsocket");
    io.emit("newMessageToClient", { /* whatever */ });
    res.sendStatus(202); // Accepted
  });

  return router;
};
```

Then use it in your `server.js` file

```js
app.use("/test", testRoutes(io));
```

Comment: thank you, you saved me :) in my case i have two routes in test file so i covered both of them with seperate functions and exported them and used thoose in server.js file like app.use("/test/", test1(io), test2())... but i don't know if it's the correct way to do it